# Proof verification : If $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $B$ with $S \subset T$, prove $f^{-1}(S)\subset f^{-1}(T)$

Tags: functions, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

EDT. **Clarification: $f:A\rightarrow B$**

EDT. Changed the first line in the proof according to responses / comments.

---

*Proof*.

Let $a \in f^{-1}(S)$. Then, $f(a)\in S$.

Because $S\subset T$, if $f(a)\in S$ then also $f(a)\in T$ and therefore $a \in f^{-1}(T)$.

For all $a \in f^{-1}(S)$ we then have $a \in f^{-1}(T)$ and therefore $f^{-1}(S)\subset f^{-1}(T)$

QED

Comment: QED, indeed ;-) Your proof is perfectly fine.

Comment: It is fine. Though I think it would be better to start from "Let $a\in f^{-1}(S)$. Then $f(a)\in S$". After all you want to prove that $f^{-1}(S)\subseteq f^{-1}(T)$.

Comment: The proof would look something like (?): Let $a \in f^{-1}(S)$. Then, $f(a)\in S$.

Because $S\subset T$, if $f(a)\in S$ then also $f(a)\in T$ and therefore $a \in f^{-1}(T)$. 

For all $a \in f^{-1}(S)$ we then have $a \in f^{-1}(T)$ and therefore $f^{-1}(S)\subset f^{-1}(T)$ 

(QED?)

Comment: Yes, now it is a perfect proof.

Comment: Okey. Thank you for your response James and Mark. It's a relief that I don't struggle *all* the time with my proof-writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your start is again wrong. You have to take $a\in f^{-1}(S)$ then you can say $f(a)\in S$  (and not vice versa).

Every time you want to prove $M\subseteq N$, you have to take $x\in M$ (and just in $M$, no $f(M)$ or $f^{-1}(M)$ or something else, just $M$)! Then you prove that $x$ is also in $N$.

Comment: I have nothing to say but a-ha. The last sentence you wrote made things clearer.